# Randomize students in Moodle

Tags: moodle

I have a Moodle classroom of about 60 students. All the students have to give a presentation. Is it possible to randomize the students in Moodle to decide the order of presentation?

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of anything in Moodle that will do that.

But you could use SQL - replace `xxx` with the course id and `RANDOM()` with the relevant random function for your database

```
SELECT RANDOM() AS randid, u.id AS userid, u.firstname, u.lastname, u.email
FROM mdl_user u
JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT ue.userid, e.courseid
    FROM mdl_user_enrolments ue
    JOIN mdl_enrol e ON e.id = ue.enrolid
) ue ON ue.userid = u.id
JOIN mdl_course c ON c.id = ue.courseid
WHERE c.id = xxx
AND u.deleted = 0
AND u.suspended = 0
ORDER BY 1
```